# VSTS Android Continuous integration build failed DexGuard license not found

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, dexguard

I'm actually working on a CI/CD using VSTS as server/git repo. I've configured the build task as showed on the website to build an android apk.
Keystores and all the data required as parameters on Build tasks are set but when I queued a Build task manually it crashes on the gradlew build module with the error:

> Can't find a DexGuard license file.
>
> You should place your license file dexguard-license.txt
>
> 1) in a location defined by the Java system property 'dexguard.license',
>
> 2) in a location defined by the OS environment variable 'DEXGUARD_LICENSE',
>
> 3) in your home directory,
>
> 4) in the class path, or
>
> 5) in the same directory as the DexGuard jar (not working in combination with  Gradle v3.1+).
>
> :app:dexguardXXXXXXXX FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardXXXXXXXX'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please check your DexGuard license (see build log for details).

But the license file is inckuded on the project and all paths on gradle properties are set correctly.

Anyone knows how to include or add the license file to VSTS in order to find the file at build time?

Comment: Can you build the project on your develop machine locally? Does it have the same issue when you build locally?

Comment: Yes, I can build it locally and there's no problems or issues about DexGuard or any other lib/extension I use.

Comment: Did you check if the license file has been uploaded to source control and downloaded during the build?